# Is a non-Jew permitted to light a menorah?

Tags: gentiles, chanuka, menora-chanukia

Is it ok/respectful for a non-Jew to light the menorah?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking this great question. I fear it is likely to get closed because of the way it is worded to be personal (see the yellow box at the top ^). If so please don't be discouraged for persuing the answer from a local Rabbi. You could try wording it more generically as well

Comment: Halachically, there's no problem with you lighting the lights, just do it as a social ceremony, without any blessings. Enjoy!

Comment: You're not hurting anything by lighting if you feel like it. I'd advise against doing it in the window or other place visible to the outside -- neighbors may think you're Jewish. I'd advise against saying the blessings, as those are about God and Jews. You could tell your kid you're doing this "because your school does it, and you like it." But yeah I hear you ... at some you'll have to have some more complicated conversations.

Comment: @RabbiKaii thanks, I accepted some edits to make the question more generic, but I'll see if I can ask at my son's school.